# Make a modal load faster

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, pageload

I have created a full page modal box to appear on pageload. I have one problem though. My homepage has to completely load before the modal shows up and I would like the modal to appear faster and not show any of my homepage. Is there any way to speed up a modal or make sure the homepage doesn't show before the modal? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Normally you would load the absolute minimum of the web page and then load everything else via AJAX. That's the most reliable way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Yahoo's [best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/) for high performance web sites (and [Google's](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro)) .

1. Instead of loading the entire page, just load the minimum to show the modal, then [post-load](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#postload) the rest.
2. If the guest is on your site before seeing the modal, [pre-load](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#preload) any resources the client will need to render the modal. If you cache these resources, that will save time when they get to the modal.
3. Eliminate unnecessary resources. For example, if your modal has an image, can it be replaced with CSS? Even a small image requires the overhead of an additional HTTP Request (unless it was preloaded).

I could go on, but these resources from Google and Yahoo are very helpful.

Comment: This is great info, but is there anything quick and easy for the time being? I'm still a beginner at javascript and do not have time to implement any involved changes.

Comment: Every homepage is different, so I can't say exactly what is making your homepage slow without more information. You don't need to use all of them, but taking the time to deeply understand these performance fundamentals will help you on all of your projects, letting you pick and choose from these options to suit a project's unique needs.